# Prove that the shift operation on regular languages preserves regularity

Tags: automata, regular-language

I have the following question:
I have seen the statement that for the Shift operation, defined as:
Shift($L$) = { $yx$ | $xy \in L$}

Where the following is mentioned: "For any regular language $L$, Shift($L$) is regular as well."

---

Shift defined as: Shift($L$) = { $yx$ | $xy \in L$}

I tried approaching this by forming a proof from the fact that a Shifted language is pulling from the same set of words / symbols as it's non shifted counterpart, but couldn't reach anything conclusive.

How would one prove that the shift operation preserves regularity?

Comment: You can try to construct a regular expression for the shifted language from the regular expression of the original one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a sketch proof, using pictures. Let's say we start with some kind of automaton which accepts the language:

[image: An automaton]

I will sketch how to construct a larger non-deterministic finite-state automaton, with $\varepsilon$ transitions (i.e. transitions between states that do not add to the word in progress), that accepts $\operatorname{Shift}(L)$.

Now, create a copy of this FSA for each state, and add a new initial state. Create $\varepsilon$ transitions from this initial state to each copy, each entering at a different state:

[image: A copy of the automaton, for each state, plus new initial state]

Let's focus one such copy, e.g.

[image]

We need a little modification here. Create a new copy of this original automaton, and add $\varepsilon$ transitions from the terminal state(s) to the initial state of the new copy. Change the terminal state(s) to not be terminal. Whichever state you arrived in, make it terminal in the copy. So, in this case:
[image]

The given non-deterministic FSA should accept $\operatorname{Shift}(L)$.

Comment: Hello, I know you posted this a while ago, but I wanted to ask in addition: Wouldn't it be possible to accept new words (thus it wouldn't fit the language) trough the ε transitions.

Comment: New words are a given, as the new language is larger than $L$. If you’re concerned that this FSA accepts more than just Shift$(L)$, then don’t be. No matter which path is taken for a given word (I.e. no matter which state it goes to first), the machine is forced to go through the previously terminal state, back to the state it started with. From the initial to the previously terminal state, we generate a word $y$. However it comes back to the new terminal state, it is forced to generate some $x$, which, in the original FSA, would have brought it to the state where $y$ began. So $xy\in L$.

Answer (score 2):

Note. The term *Shift* is not really appropriate and *conjugate* would possibly be better.

Let ${\cal A} = (Q, A, \cdot, i, F)$ be the minimal automaton of $L$. For each state $p, q \in Q$, let $L_{p, q}$ be the language accepted by $\cal A$ with $p$ as initial state and $q$ as the unique
final state. I claim that
\begin{equation}
 \text{Shift}(L) = \bigcup_{q \in Q, f \in F}L_{q,f} L_{i,q}  \quad (*)
\end{equation}
Let $R$ be the right hand side of $(*)$. Let $w \in
\text{Shift}(L)$. Then $w = vu$ for some words $u$ and $v$ such that $uv \in L$. Let $q = i \cdot u$ and $f = q\cdot v$. Then $i \cdot uv = q \cdot v = f$, and since $uv \in L$, one has $f \in F$. Now since $v \in L_{q,f}$ and $u \in L_{i,q}$, one gets $vu \in R$, which shows that $\text{Shift}(L) \subseteq R$.

Let now $w \in R$. By definition, there exists $q \in Q$ and $f \in F$ such that $w \in L_{q,f} L_{i,q}$, that is, $w = vu$ with $v \in L_{q,f}$ and $u \in L_{i,q}$. It follows that $i \cdot uv = q \cdot v$ and hence $uv \in L$. Thus $R \subseteq \text{Shift}(L)$, which proves (*). It follows immediately that $L$ is regular.